# Update json string column with proper json in Postgres SQL

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a column which type is JSON but it contains JSON strings like this:

```
"{\"a\":1,\"b\":2,\"c\":3}"
```

I want to update the values in the column with proper JSON objects without the quotes and escapes like this:

```
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}
```

I've tried the following statement even tough it says it does update rows, the columns are still the same.

```
UPDATE table SET column = to_json(column);
```

It seems like the `to_json` function doesn't work since it is a JSON string?

How can I update those values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could cast the JSON column as text, remove the unwanted quotes and escapes, and then cast the resulting text as JSON.

```
update tbl
set js = trim(replace(js::text, '\',''), '"')::json
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/ca22GUG4)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`#>>` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) to extract the string and then convert it back to JSON with `::json`:

```
UPDATE your_table
SET your_column = (your_column #>> '{}')::json;
```

A fully working [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Z9eWpeXG):

```
create table your_table (
    your_column json
);

insert into your_table (your_column) values ('"{\"a\":1,\"b\":2,\"c\":3}"'::json);

select your_column, your_column #>> '{}'
from your_table ;
```

| your_column | ?column? |
| --- | --- |
| `"{\"a\":1,\"b\":2,\"c\":3}"` | `{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}` |

```
update your_table
set your_column = (your_column #>> '{}')::json;

select *
from your_table;
```

| your_column |
| --- |
| `{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}` |